# escaping space in bash shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line, escaping

I am trying to use WinExe to execute a command line on a Windows machine. So far I am able to execute a file (sha256sum.exe) and pass parameter like "--help" to it but I am not able to pass any filename with space in it.

Here is how my command line looks like-

```
./winexe --ostype=2  -U username --password passworsGoesHere //hostIP "cmd /c  \"\"%programfiles%\\MyApp\\tools\\sha256sum.exe\"\" \"c:\1 1.txt\" "
```

The filename is `1 1.txt` under `C:\` and output of command is -

```
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

If I execute this-

```
./winexe --ostype=2  -U username --password passworsGoesHere //hostIP "cmd /c  \"\"%programfiles%\\MyApp\\tools\\sha256sum.exe\"\" --help "
```

it works.

Comment: use single quote instead of douoble

Comment: `./winexe --ostype=2  -U username --password passworsGoesHere //hostIP 'cmd /c  "%programfiles%\\MyApp\\tools\\sha256sum.exe c:\\1 1.txt"'` i meant this way

Comment: and you didn't escaped backslash `\"c:\1 1.txt\"`

Answer (score 1):

Try doubling-up your quotation marks as you did for the `sha256sum` command.

```
./winexe --ostype=2  -U username --password passworsGoesHere //hostIP "cmd /c  \"\"%programfiles%\\MyApp\\tools\\sha256sum.exe\"\" \"\"c:\1 1.txt\"\" "
```